# Coudn't scroll to end of the page using window.scrollTo

Tags: javascript, css, webview

I am not able to scroll all the way until end. Following code stop working near the end of page.

I have used following methods to scroll programmatically,

```
// 1 still see scrolling left
window.scrollTo(x,y) > window.scrollTo(window.scrollWidth,0)
window.scrollBy(x,y) >
// 2
scrollingElement.scrollLeft = scrollingElement.scrollWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth;
```

**Info:**

Some width related info for my case,

```
window.scrollWidth > 6180
scrollingElement.scrollWidth > 6183
document.documentElement.clientWidth > 412
```

**Note:** I have used `webkitColumnGap` css and turned vertical page into horizontal. That's why I have bigger `scrollWidth`.

If I use following (full scroll) I still see, there is some scrolling left and I can use mouse to scroll that part,

```
window.scrollTo(window.scrollWidth,0) // go to end
scrollingElement.scrollLeft = <full width> // go to end

// log scroll position for inpection ~ this number does not match the full width
window.scrollX ~ 4k
(window.pageXOffset || doc.scrollLeft) - (doc.clientLeft || 0) ~ 4k
```

I have run out of ideas so would need help from you guys to find out the issue.

**Browser details:**

I am using flutter `Webview` in android device.

**Edit:**

After lot of trial and error adding following css fixed the issue, I don't why this fixed it?

```
body {
  overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not answerable without a [mcve]. It's also unclear what `end` means in this case. You're not able to scroll to the `left` end or to the `right` end? If it's the `left` end, chances are it's for using some centering technique where the children are wider than the available parent space. If it's the `right` end, it's likely a case of a margin on one of the inner elements or hard-coding a width somewhere along the parents tree. But, again, your haven't provided enough technical detail to make the question answerable.

Comment: @tao I will try to make github repo for this problem.

Comment: You might want to have a look at what codesanbox.io has to offer (multi-file node based environment). They also have a "server" version. And remember you only need to repro the bug, not your entire app.

Comment: @tao I tried bare bone html with just paragraphs removed all css it worked fine looks like html which I have is creating some sort of issue with overflow.

Comment: That's because the issue is with CSS. Why would you remove all CSS from a CSS related issue? It's like removing all engines from a formula one race.

Comment: @tao yet i am aiming to do that now. remove them one by one and see which one is the culprit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214359/discussion-between-tao-and-jbaba).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After lot of trial and error adding following css fixed the issue, I don't why this fixed it?

```
body {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

This means that some of your children elements bled out of its parent container. `overflow: hidden` tells the browser to cut out the parts that are not fitting inside the body container. That also means that this issue can be solved by changing the size or positioning of the body's children, and that would probably be a better approach to fixing the issue.

By default, `overflow` is set to `visible`, and therefore the browser allows you to see (and to scroll) outside of the containing box [(overflow property explained)](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

The `!important` part tells the browser to artificially increase the specificity of this rule. For more details on specificity: [css-tricks/sprecificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Answer (score 2):

You want to scroll to the bottom?
Try this:

```js
var height = document.body.scrollHeight
window.scroll(0, height)
```

Hope i understood your question correctly

Comment: I think you missed my note part. I am using horizontal scrolling `(css:  webkitColumnGap)` and i have tried full scroll `scrollTo(6180,0)`

Comment: Okay so i don't understand what the purpose of this is.

But if you just want to scroll horizontally to 100% right

```
var width = document.body.scrollWidth
window.scroll(width, 0)
```

or is the problem that it's not scrolling if the width is > 4k?

Comment: okay this helps i will refine my question. I am saying here if I use `window.scroll(width, 0)` it does not reach to the end. I still see there is scrolling left. and that 4k number is log statement after i scroll to the end.

Comment: and what if you put a crazy number in the scroll function like window.scroll(9999999999999, 0) ?

Comment: yup even that does not reach the end. but after that crazy number if i check the my current scroll position that shows me i am at this number 4000 and i log what is full scroll width that's 6183. so what happened during crazy number?

Comment: really odd,
I'm sad to say that i don't have a clue how i can help you with that weird bug

Comment: yup I know. I did alot debugging i added those logs and my dimensions here but your answer did helped me refined mine question so thanks for that.